# I'm trying to implement a binary tree. My program stops abruptly after a few node insertions. What is going wrong?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm just trying out implementation of binary tree. It's not for a college class so I cannot ask a teacher :(

I have tried debugging it with the Codeblocks debugger but I'm still not understanding what is going wrong.

I am using class instead of struct. Currently I have only implemented insertion and inorder traversal functions.
For insertion function, I am checking if the root node is NULL or not. If it is NULL, the newNode becomes equal to the root node. Or else, I find the appropriate parent node and then append the newNode as its child.

And, in the inorder traversal function, is my recursion correct?

Edit: Turns out that I wasn't initializing my Node variables. My code is working after initializing those variables. Thanks for your help!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* left_child;
    Node* right_child;
};

Node* root = NULL;
void insertion();
void inorder_travesal(Node*);

int main(){
    char ch;
    do{ 
        int choice;
        cout<<"\nEnter your choice: \n1. Insertion\n2. Inorder Traversal\n : ";
        cin>>choice;

        switch(choice){
            case 1: insertion();
                    break;

            case 2: inorder_travesal(root);
                    break;
        }

        cout<<"\nDo you want to continue?: ";
        cin>>ch;

    }while(ch == 'y');


    return 0;
}

void insertion(){
    int data;
    cout<<"\nEnter data: ";
    cin>>data;

    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temp = root;

        while(true){

            if(temp->data > newNode->data)
            {
                if(temp->left_child == NULL)
                {
                    temp->left_child = newNode;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = temp->left_child;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(temp->right_child == NULL)
                {
                    temp->right_child = newNode;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = temp->right_child;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inorder_travesal(root);
}

void inorder_travesal(Node* temp){

    if(temp->left_child != NULL){
        inorder_travesal(temp->left_child);
    }

    cout<<temp->data<<" ";

    if(temp->right_child != NULL){
        inorder_travesal(temp->right_child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialise your `Node` members and try again.

Comment: What problem are you having with this code? What sort of output are you getting, and what are you expecting?